# Data object with array of different groups, trying to display ordered by group type using .map() and pushing to new array nothing is rendering

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a React Component I'm building out that accepts a data object as props.

This data object holds an array of groups each with it's own group type.

What I'm trying to do is map over each group in the array and display it's contents as it's own section, but I also want to ensure that all of the objects with the type *grid* display together, followed by any sections with a *list* type no matter what position they are in the array.

So even if the array holds the values like:

```
[{Grid}, {List}, {Grid}, {List}, {Grid}]
```

It will display like this:

```
Group #1 (Grid)
    Contents

Group #2 (Grid)
    Contents

Group #3 (Grid)
    Contents

Group #4 (List)
    Contents

Group #5 (List)
    Contents
```

The problem I'm having is that I wrote two separate components to handle the styling of each type and then passed them into a function that creates a new array from the original to then render, and nothing is displaying. I'm not getting any error messages or anything in the console so I'm completely stumped as to where I'm going wrong.

Here are my components, the data structure and a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-meadow-xlwuq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark):

```
// Component File
import "./styles.css";
import data from "./resourceMock";
import FileIcon from "./FileIcon";

const GridView = (group) => {
  const { groupName, items } = group;

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{groupName}</h2>
      <ul
        style={{
          display: "inline-flex",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          listStyleType: "none"
        }}
      >
        {items.map((item) => {
          return (
            <li style={{ height: "40vh", flexGrow: 1 }}>
              <img src={item.img} style={{ height: "150px", width: "150px" }} />
              <h4>{item.name}</h4>
              <h5>{item.subtitle}</h5>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

const ListView = (group) => {
  const { groupName, items } = group;

  return (
    <>
      <h2>{groupName}</h2>
      <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}>
        {items.map((item) => {
          return (
            <li>
              <FileIcon />
              {item.title}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};

function renderList(group) {
  const lists = [];

  if (!group) return null;

  data.map((group) => {
    switch (group.groupType) {
      case "grid":
        return lists.push((group) => {
          <GridView group={group} />;
        });
      case "list":
        return lists.push((group) => {
          <ListView group={group} />;
        });
      default:
        return lists.push((group) => {
          <ListView group={group} />;
        });
    }
  });

  return lists;
}

export default function App() {
  return <div className="App">{data.map((group) => renderList(group))}</div>;
}
```

Data Structure:

```
export default [
  {
    groupName: "Marvel Characters",
    groupType: "grid",
    items: [
      {
        name: "Iron Man",
        subtitle: "Inventor Tony Stark",
        img:
          "https://www.denofgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/mcu-1-iron-man.jpg?resize=768%2C432"
      },
      {
        name: "Incredible Hulk",
        subtitle: "Bruce Banner",
        img:
          "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/-jHnFcGLqlxjdOl9Mf99UPBk4XJKcQ1Hsv7lPYEs8Vai874sW0l5TUwn3acriwGpE36aUDPpZHPFzccRUt7b7POGOWCFIbgYomTO9bDCXF0eovxFGdr_D3P-0wfLnkUMOOJDG09MgAzqSCbiDq-A"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: "Magic Cards",
    groupType: "list",
    items: [
      {
        title: "Kamahl, Fist Of Krosa",
        link:
          "https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=220490"
      },
      {
        title: "Seedborn Muse",
        link:
          "https://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=446180"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: "DC Characters",
    groupType: "grid",
    items: [
      {
        name: "Batman",
        subtitle: "Bruce Wayne",
        img:
          "https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/marvel_dc/images/a/a6/Batman_Vol_2_2_Variant_Textless.jpg/revision/latest/top-crop/width/360/height/450?cb=20120228075313"
      },
      {
        name: "Martian Manhunter",
        subtitle: "J'onn J'onzz",
        img:
          "https://cdn.flickeringmyth.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Martian-Manhunter-600x338.png"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: "Kaiju and Mechs",
    groupType: "grid",
    items: [
      {
        name: "Godzilla",
        img:
          "https://www.denofgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/godzillakingofmonsters-2.jpg?resize=768%2C432"
      },
      {
        name: "Hunter Vertigo",
        img: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7F-iZYAqSbw/maxresdefault.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    groupName: "Comic Books",
    groupType: "list",
    items: [
      {
        title: "Descender",
        link: "https://imagecomics.com/comics/series/descender"
      },
      {
        title: "East of West",
        link: "https://imagecomics.com/comics/series/east-of-west"
      },
      {
        title: "Letter 44",
        link: "https://onipress.com/collections/letter-44"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issues.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-sinoussi-5suro

You are already looping over `data` inside renderList, so we can directly have `<div className="App">{renderList(data)}</div>;`

To sort, we can use `Array.sort()`

`data.sort((a, b) => a.groupType === b.groupType ? 0 : a.groupType > b.groupType ? 1 : -1);`

Also, in switch case you need to push the component and not a function.

```
case "grid":
        lists.push(<GridView group={group} />);
        break;
```

Need to use destructuring here `const ListView = ({ group }) => {}`

Finally add `key` to your lists. I have added using the item name, but you need to change per your requirement.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Is there a way to organize the elements so that Grids are grouped together followed by Lists?

Comment: Updated answer.